# PHPMailer fails after one email in Cron Job

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

I have php code that loops through client emails and sends them reports using PHPMailer. When run in a browser, it works perfectly. I created a cron job that is able to open and run the php file. However when the cron job runs, the first email is sent but the program stops sending emails. After testing I realized after the first email is sent, the rest of the code stops working and it never loops through to the next 'while' condition.

cron job used (which does open and run the file):

```
 /usr/bin/php -q site1/temp/test.php
```

The code below will send 3 emails when opened in a browser, but only sends one when run with a cron job:

```
   <?php

        $index = 0;

        while($index < 3){ 

            require (dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

                //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

                $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'my smtp provider';                          // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username = 'name';                 // SMTP username
                $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                $mail->From = 'email';
                $mail->FromName = 'ME';

                $mail->AddAddress( "test@yahoo.com" );              

                $mail->isHTML(true);                                 

                $mail->Subject = 'Test email';

                $mail->Body    =    "test";

                $mail->send();
               //  nothing else is sent at this point after the first loop through

        }//end while
 ?>
```

NOTE: using Linux Server (Parallels Plesk)

Comment: I'd advise using `require_once`, not `require` in this case, and moving that statement to the first line of the script

Comment: That worked. I owe you a beer my friend. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
        require (dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $index = 0;
        while($index < 3){ 

                $mail = new PHPMailer;

                //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

                $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'my smtp provider';                          // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username = 'name';                 // SMTP username
                $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                $mail->From = 'email';
                $mail->FromName = 'ME';

                $mail->AddAddress( "test@yahoo.com" );              

                $mail->isHTML(true);                                 

                $mail->Subject = 'Test email';

                $mail->Body    =    "test";

                if(!$mail->Send()) {
                  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                  echo "Message sent!";
                }
                $mail->clearAddresses();
                $index++;
        }
 ?>
```

Using $mail->clearAddresses(); within the loop. and Check which type of error you get.

Comment: No reason to call `clearAddresses` if you're creating a new instance every time, though that's inefficient - see my comment on the Q.

Comment: yes you also not use $index++; so I will be Infinite loop.

Comment: Also you can declare require out of loop.